# How to push and pull remotes to bare repository in git

Tags: git

I have my local repository with the "origin" remote configured ("origin" is a bare repository). I also have some other remotes configured. Is it possible to push my configured remotes (the names and the adresses, not the content) to the "origin".

The intention is that if somebody clones the project from the "origin" that he automatically has all the other remotes configured like I have.
Or do I have to add all remote repositories automatically after each clone?

Answer (score 1):

You can't control someone else's repository.  Push access to the content of a repository isn't the same thing, at all, as administrative control.  To get that, you need access to the repository's filesystem.  As the repository administrator you could grant controlled remote access to its configuration by setting up a post-receive hook to look for e.g. files pushed to a special branch name and have its way with whatever it finds there.

Perhaps the easiest thing would be to supply a "append-me-to-config-in-the-.git-directory" file with the `[remote "whosis"]` sections included, all set up for them.  Or you could put the necessary config commands in the README so doing the setup is 'V}!sh' in vi or however you get your editor to run commands on buffer contents.